# How do I make Opera Javascript save redirects to history so history.go(-1) works?

Tags: javascript, redirect, opera

I am using window.location* to redirect across a number of pages.

There are 3 pages, a, b and c.

a links to b
b redirects to c

I then use history.go(-1) in c to go back from c to b but in Opera it goes to a.

What would work in Opera? This works in IE8 and Firefox, as it should.

(* tried window.location.href too, still does not work.
window.location.replace would not work because it would kill c from the history list)
)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to tied it to the window?

```
window.history.go(-1)
```